# Does changing factor labels in R change the predictions?

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic-regression

For example I gave 0 to tested positive and 1 for negative my question is I want 
To give 1 to positive and 0 to negative do I have to change 
y.pred <- ifelse(prob.pred > 0.5,0,1)
To :
y.pred <- ifelse(prob.pred > 0.5,1,0)

It so confusing me,  is me code :

```
df$class <- factor(df$class, levels = c('tested_positive','tested_negative'),
               labels = c(0,1))

library(caTools)
set.seed(123)
split <- sample.split(df$class, SplitRatio = 0.75)
training_set = subset(df, split == TRUE)
test_set = subset(df, split == FALSE)

classifier <- glm(formula = class ~ .
              , family = binomial,
              data = training_set)
prob.pred <- predict(classifier, newdata =test_set[-9], type = 'response')

y.pred <- ifelse(prob.pred > 0.5,0,1)
cm = table(test_set[,9], y.pred > 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just change the factor label assignment. So as you already said assign 1 to tested_positive and 0 to tested_negative like so:

```
df$class <- factor(df$class, levels = c('tested_positive','tested_negative'),
                   labels = c(1,0))
```

But make sure to always assign classes in predictions according to

```
y.pred <- ifelse(prob.pred > 0.5,1,0)
```

Because the model predicts P(y=1|X), so if P(y=1|X) > 0.5 then y = 1 otherwise y=0 (you did it the other way round in your code.

Comment: okey thanks I understood, but when we change labels what are we changing exactly?

Comment: I just tried it the problem is the output still the same and the prediction the same but labels are flipped so I think it's wrong , it's so confusing Im lost now I don't know which one should be 0 and which one should be 1